# import django.http from HttpResponse ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: django

I am trying to run this but getting syntax error
    import django.http from HttpResponse
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

```
import django.http from HttpResponse


def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello")
```

Answer (score 4):

**Short answer**: swap `import` and `from`.

---

You swapped the `from` and the `import` keywords in your import statement. If you want to import an identifier from a module, you write this as:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
```

So you first write `from`, then the name of the module, then the `import` keyword, and finally a comma separated list of identifiers to imprt.

Comment: Yea got it, Thank you so much.